# how to configure mysql workbench (mac version) not to append the @localhost in the mysql login

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

After specify mysql user name, workbench (6.0.9.11421 build 1170) will always append the "@localhost". Is there any way to let workbench just use the configured user name to login?

The issue is  the user@localhost & user@% are two totally independent users. I don't need this xxx@localhost

MySQL config: (use "root" instead of "'root'@'172.31.5.133'" will got same issue, mysql server query will return "root@localhost" as the connected user)
[image: Mysql Config]

Connection User from MySQL:
[image]

Another tool, Sequel pro, works perfectly without the above issue

Connection config:

[image]

Connection User from query:

[image: Sequel pro connection result]

Answer (score 1):

When you ssh and mysql, you are connecting to the MySQL database from the ssh. That is why the @localhost appears. If you were to directly connect to it without sshing, the localhost will disappear.

Comment: But when I connect to Mysql through SSH using the command line, there is no such issue. And I do test the directly connect to the server without SSH, the result is same. workbench will append the '@localhost'. And this SSH server is different from the mysql server. I update my question with the test result from another Mysql tool. Thanks.

Comment: @Dreamer It looks like you're using mac os x. I suggest you simply use Sequel Pro.

Comment: @Dreamer Why are you writing out 'root'@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx? You can simply say root?

Comment: from the query result, you can tell, sequel pro, return the user is from 172.31.2.105, while the Mysql server is in 172.31.5.133, which they are 2 different servers. one is AWS EC2 instance, another one is RDS instance.

Comment: :)... But I love workbench for the modelling although its mac UI has some issues.

Comment: From the query result for the workbench connection, it will always append the local even I try to use the mysql host specific syntax. It means just filling root, will also return the login as 'root@localhost' from the mysql server side.

Comment: @Dreamer I'm trying to emulate the issue as well, but mine shows up correctly. Sorry :/

Comment: speechless..... another my private issue ;(. last time, I report another issue and corrected byMike Lischke. Hope I can get it right after a while. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench will not always append "@localhost". It uses the host setting you specified in the connection settings.

**Update:**

The host can be set in the connection management wizard which you can reach, for instance, by right clicking on a tile and selecting "Edit Connection...":

[image]

Comment: Where do I find the setting? Tanks a lot for any clue.

Comment: Answer updated. Didn't expect you don't know where to set up a connection (since you connected already).

Comment: That is the place I add the user name. But if I put the root there, the result will be always root@localhost. Even I try the mysql host syntax 'root'@'172.31.5.133', it still append the localhost. But I don't have this similar issue in command line. I put my detail config in the question. Thanks.